# Does all "going to" s here mean the same?

Tags: word-meaning

> When you back up the car **you're going to** back it up until your body is even with the middle portion of the trunk on the other car. Then at that point **you're going to** turn your wheel **all the way** to the right, and **you're going to** create an angle. What you're **going to do** is your car is **going to be in a position like** this when you turn the wheel to the right, OK.

I have a greatvdeal of time figuring out what all these **going to** s really mean . Does all of them mean the same here? I know what it means. It is talking about something that would hapoen in the future. But all these in this short speech is confusing .

Comment: The person speaking in this driving video, really is not using very good English.

Answer (score 2):

No, all of these "*going to*"'s do not mean quite the same things.  Most of them mean the usual "*you should*" or "*you will*", but two of them mean the less common "*this causes to happen*", or more simply, "*thus*" or "*therefore*".

Editing this paragraph into better English would look something like this:

> When you back up the car **you should** back it up until your body is even with the middle portion of the trunk on the other car. Then at that point **you should** turn your wheel all the way to the right, and **this will** create an angle. What **you should have accomplished** is your car **will be in** a position like this when you turn the wheel to the right.